# open file in webview xamarin form not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

i have implemented open file in webview using xamarin form. It is working fine, the problem i am getting when i click on open file file dialougue will open where i can see all my files, if i dont selecy any thing and click on back button from mobile, open file doesnt work again. If i keep sending file it works fine but if open file and dont choose any image and just go back open file doesnt work again.
here is my code
MainActivity

```
 public void StartActivity(Intent intent, int requestCode, Action<int, Result, Intent> resultCallback)
        {
            this.resultCallbackvalue = resultCallback;
            StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (this.resultCallbackvalue != null)
            {
                this.resultCallbackvalue(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                this.resultCallbackvalue = null;
            }
            //Platform.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

MyWebViewRenderer class

```
public class MyWebClient : WebChromeClient
        {
            private static int filechooser = 1;
            private IValueCallback message;
            MainActivity mContext;
            public MyWebClient(MainActivity context)
            {
                this.mContext = context;
            }
            public override bool OnShowFileChooser(Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                this.message = filePathCallback;
                Intent chooserIntent = fileChooserParams.CreateIntent();
                chooserIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
                this.mContext.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(chooserIntent, "File Chooser"), filechooser, this.OnActivityResult);
                return true;
            }
            private void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    if (requestCode == filechooser)
                    {
                        if (null == this.message)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        this.message.OnReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.ParseResult((int)resultCode, data));
                        this.message = null;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: If you open file and dont choose any image and just go back open file, `OnActivityResult` method will be executed. why you add `OnActivityResult` in `MainActivity.cs`. xamarin forms just use one activity in his all lifecycle.

Comment: i have OnActivityResult on MyWebViewRenderer, should i remove OnActivityResult  from mainactivity?

Comment: i have tried to remove OnActivityResult from mainactivity, but still not working

Comment: Can you share a demo about this issue?

Comment: how to share demo?

Comment: when i open file and share file its working fine, but when i open file and dont choose any image and go back then click again on open file, open diaglouge doesn't open

Comment: You can update your demo(please do not share project completely, just share a project that could reproduce his issue) to github or Google drive. And post this url here.

Comment: its not possible this project connected with many things and its working in local right now even if i upload it wont work if u want a video demo i can share video in google drive

Comment: any help for this issue?